# With bootstrap-vue: How to add a class to the page buttons in a b-pagination component

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

Imagine I have a .vue file and I'm using `bootstrap-vue` in my vue component with this code in the template:

```
<b-pagination
  :total-rows="totalRows"
  :per-page="perPage"
/>
```

It will be compiled in the following output code in the browser page:

```
<ul class="pagination b-pagination">
  <li class="page-item active">
    <a href="#" class="page-link btn-primary">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item">
    <a href="#" class="page-link btn-light">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item">
    <a href="#" class="page-link btn-light">3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

From the .vue file, how do I add a class to the `a` element of the pagination component?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can add a class to the `a` element, but you can select the `a` element in CSS using the following:

```
.b-pagination li .page-link {
  //CSS rules
}
```

Comment: I need to **add** a class, I am fine with css selectors, thank you.  :)

Comment: Then you might consider using javascript to add the class, as I don't see this feature in the documentation.